# Mysqld changes pid

Tags: mysql, percona

I have this really strange problem.

To give you some context, I've have a script that setsup my dev env which contains mysql and percona server and some other things using brew on OSX. 
I've re-runned it to do some reconfiguration that got messed up. 
But after the re-run mysql won't stay up. Every time I check the mysqld pid I get a different result. I checked the mysql logs and the problem is "mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists".

So I decided to delete everything related to mysql. I followed the gist from https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d but somehow, the mysql and mysqld process still starts after I restart my laptop.

How is this possible? Has anyone else had this problem? How do I fix it without reinstalling OSX?

Comment: Keep a close eye on the MySQL log. It might be crashing and restarting.

Comment: Yeah, but that's what I don't understand. The gist should've deleted the mysql, how does it still starts when I restart my pc and who is starting it? Are the mysqld logs stored separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So tadman was right. I managed to get my environment to work, I still don't know what that zombie process is, but because it's not affecting me, I don't care.

The problem was that my script was installing the latest version of MySQL and percona-server@5.6. and there is a conflict with InnoDB.

After reinstalling manually everything in the MySQL log there was something along the lines:

```
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

After installing MySQL@5.6 everything seems to work as expected.

Thanks tadman.